# How do I backup a database with a stored procedure in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-backups

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that backs up a database, however whenever I execute it, the folder I'm trying to backup to remains empty.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
USE [HarvestMan_SoutheskFarm_03_05_22]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      Will Sewell
-- Create date: 03-05-2022
-- Description: Procedure to back up a database
-- =============================================

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BackupDatabases] 
    @name VARCHAR(MAX) = 'HarvestMan_SoutheskFarm_03_05_22' -- DB NAME TO CREATE BACKUP
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path of backup files
    DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup
    DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name

    SET @path = 'C:\Users\will.sewell\Documents\Database_Test'

    -- specify filename format
    SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)

    BEGIN
        SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'

        BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName
    END
END
```

I have tried changing the drive that it is writing to.

I've copy and pasted the database name I want to backup to ensure no spelling mistakes.

I'm assuming it might be a permissions issue or a visible files in the folder.

When I execute the stored procedure, I get this:

```
Processed 24472 pages for database 'HarvestMan_SoutheskFarm_03_05_22', file 'HarvestMan_dat' on file 2.

Processed 1 pages for database 'HarvestMan_SoutheskFarm_03_05_22', file 'HarvestMan_log' on file 2. BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 24473 pages in 5.039 seconds (37.941 MB/sec).

Completion time: 2022-05-04T10:27:30.2344290+01:00
```

Comment: If there is a permission error, you will get an error from the procedure. What are the messages/errors you get when you execute the procedure?

Comment: Though, I will admit, it is *very* unlikely that the SQL Server Service account will have access to a user's Documents folder.

Comment: Sorry I should have included that. I will edit it into the post.

Comment: You are backing up to folder `C:\Users\will.sewell\Documents` with name `Database_TestHarvestMan_SoutheskFarm_03_05_22_20220504.bak`. You missed a backslash between `@path` and `@name`

Comment: Note the backup file is created on the server, not the SSMS machine.

Comment: @Dan Guzman I thought I would get it as a .bak file in that folder? I'm not sure where I can access this backup then.

Comment: You need to navigate to the files on the host that SQL Server is hosted on, @WilliamSewell .

Comment: Great that makes sense. Thank you. Someone post it as solution and i'll accept.

Comment: _'HarvestMan_SoutheskFarm_03_05_22'_ NEVER NEVER NEVER use 2 digit years - no matter how trivial it might seem. Y2K was a real thing. If you sort these strings - which you might likely do for files in a directly, use a format that facilitates sorting by date since people tend to do that. And don't provide a default name - that's just lazy coding and lazy usage. There is no reasonable default - don't encourage this.

Comment: 03_05_22, it's that May 22, 2003, or March 5, 2022?

Answer (score 0):

Dear you have to create the stored procedure first
also your path missing the last slash

BIG Note you must define an actual path

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BackupDatabases] 
    @name VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ActualDataBaseName' -- DB NAME TO                                 CREATE BACKUP
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path of backup files
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name

SET @path = 'C:\ActualPath\'

-- specify filename format
SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)

BEGIN
    SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'

    BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName
END
END
```